# Unzip a file present in S3 and upload it back to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a 50 GB zip files which contains a lot of folder/subfolders/files in it. Is there any way I can unzip this file and upload it back to S3 without downloading this file?

I tried using Lambda for this process, but ran into space issues. Is there any way I can use glue for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use Glue for this. [This guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started.html) should help you setting up your environment.

You will need to use several workers to handle such a file size, according to the documentation 1 G1.X worker has 16 GB of memory, so you will need at least 5 (1 Driver, 4 executors).

Comment: Turns out that Glue can't handle zip files. It can only handle gzip and bzip2 compressed files. Any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Amazon S3 does not have a Zip/Unzip capability. Therefore, the zip file would need to be downloaded *somewhere*, unzipped, and then the content would need to be uploaded.

There are various examples online of people attempting to *stream* a zip file and send the resulting data to S3 without saving locally (eg within an AWS Lambda function), but this still involves downloading the content to unzip (or at least streaming it, which means downloading without saving).

Frankly, the easiest method is to use an Amazon EC2 instance to download, unzip and upload.

Comment: I haven't actually ever used EC2. Is there any tutorial you can link me to learn about accessing S3 from EC2?

Comment: Look for a YouTube video showing how to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has simple commands to upload/download files and directories. You can run it on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance. The reason I would recommend EC2 is that it is very fast talking with S3 buckets in the same Region, and avoids Data Transfer costs that are incurred when sending data to the Internet. An EC2 instance is just a Windows or Linux virtual computer, so once you login commands are the same as a normal computer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and have solved it by utilising Java s3 sdk library. As you say key here is that since the files are large you want to "stream" the content, without keeping any data in memory or writing to disk.

I've made a library that can be used for this purpose and is available in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22io.github.nejckorasa%22%20AND%20a:%22s3-stream-unzip%22), here is the GitHub link: [nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip](https://github.com/nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip)